# Null Reference On Extracting Data From JSon File

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to extract data from json file but when I click on a button it gives an exception of NullReference, In fact there is a data in json file but still it gives an exception.

```
//Json File Starts With Name myfile
[
{"Name" : "Stack" , "Surname" : "OverFlow"},
{"Name" : "Google", "Surname" : "INc"}
]
```

//Json File Ends

```
 [DataContract]
class dt { 
   public dt(){}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
}

  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile sf = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\myfile.txt");
        var dataString = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sf);
        DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<dt>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString));
        List<dt> myData = (List<dt>)json.ReadObject(ms);


            foreach (var dt in myData)
            {

                    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(dt.Name.ToString() +" "+ dt.Surname.ToString());
                    await md.ShowAsync();

            }



    }
```

Comment: As your reading the file it would be useful to remove the //comment from the top then it just becomes a json valid string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and data contract serialization using explicit [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is opt-in.  What that means is that each member you want to be serialized must be marked with [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You can also explicitly create a data contract by using DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute attributes. This is normally done by applying the DataContractAttribute attribute to the type. This attribute can be applied to classes, structures, and enumerations. The DataMemberAttribute attribute must then be applied to each member of the data contract type to indicate that it is a data member, that is, it should be serialized.

Thus your `dt` class must look like:

```
[DataContract]
class dt { 
   public dt(){}
   [DataMember]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

You are getting the null reference because `dt.Name` and `dt.Surname`, not being serialized, are left `null`.

(Incidentally, since those two members are already strings, there is no need to call `ToString()` on them.)

Comment: Good answer. Just as a small addition: If you don't want to use `explicit` attributes you could also thinking of using [Json.NET Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which can be installed via Nuget.